# Append to arbitrarily nested list

Tags: r

I have a nested, list structure that I am using as the basis for a class. Each class object can contain an instance of another class object which will be used for chaining a series of commands. I am trying to overload the `+` operator to be able to iteratively build up a collection of commands. This requires finding the "deepest" command and appending to it. This is where I am not having any luck.

```
# an aribitrarily nested list
tmp <- list(x = list(x = list(x = list())))

# find deepest 'x'
last.x <- function(e) {
  while(!is.null(e$x)){
    e <- e$x
  }
  return(e)
}

# I need to be able to append to the deepest 'x' in the list. Ideally:
last.x(tmp)$x <- list()
```

Which yields the error:

```
Error in last.x(tmp)[["x"]] <- list() : 
  could not find function "last.x<-"
```

What I'm looking for is some way to access the "deepest" x by reference and append a child to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you extract some values from a data structure in R and then change the extracted object, this won't affect the original data structure (aka the extracted object won't act like a pointer to the original data). For instance, consider copying the species from the iris dataset and then changing the extracted values:

```
species <- iris$Species
species[1] <- "virginica"
species[1]
# [1] virginica
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
iris$Species[1]
# [1] setosa
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

However, you can still accomplish what you want to do by constructing a new nested list with the child added at the lowest level. Here's a way to do it with a recursive function:

```
tmp
# $x
# $x$x
# $x$x$x
# list()

rec <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x$x))  return(list(x=list()))
  else  return(list(x=rec(x$x)))
}
rec(tmp)
# $x
# $x$x
# $x$x$x
# $x$x$x$x
# list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing my solution in hopes that it is useful to others. Thanks to [josilber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093387/josilber) for providing the inspiration. In trying to create a simple example I excluded some details that made it difficult to apply the answer directly.

Start with three objects, each a list of depth 1:

```
obj1 <- structure(list(), class='obj')
obj2 <- structure(list(), class='obj')
obj3 <- structure(list(), class='obj')
```

Custom addition function that nests subsequent objects one level deeper:

```
`+.obj` <- function(e1, e2) {  
  if (is.null(e1$x)) {
    e1$x <- e2
  } else {
    e1$x <- e1$x + e2
  }
  return(e1)  
}
```

Example output

```
res <- obj1 + obj2 + obj3

> str(res)
List of 1
 $ x:List of 1
  ..$ x: list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "obj"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "obj"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "obj"
```